# Why can't I add data (rows and values) to my wp database?

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I want to add some data to my Wordpress database. The Table was already created by using this code in my plugins main file:

```
function create_schedule_table() {
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_tablename"; 
   if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
           $sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
           id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           time datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' NOT NULL,
           name tinytext NOT NULL,
           text text NOT NULL,
           url VARCHAR(55) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
           UNIQUE KEY id (id)
           );";

           require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
           dbDelta( $sql );
   }
}
```

That worked perfectly. But now the user should be able to save data by clicking a button. By clicking the button a secondary PHP script within my plugins directory is executed. Within that file I enable the use of wordpress functions with: `require_once("../../../wp-load.php");` and initialize the wpdb variable with `global $wpdb;`

I try to save something to my table with:

```
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "my_tablename";
$test='toast';
$wpdb->insert('wp_my_tablename',
    array(
        'monday'=>$test        
    ),
    array(
        '%s'
    )
);
```

But unfortunately nothing changes. I tried to debug or get an error but couldn't find anything so far. This:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_my_tablename");
var_dump($result);
```

just returned an empty array.

```
exit( var_dump( $wpdb->last_query ) );
```

returned:

```
string(60) "INSERT INTO `wp_my_tablename` (`monday`) VALUES ('toast')"
```

So where is the error? How could I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off [Don't include wp-load](http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/) but use a normal [ajax call](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins).
Second you appear to insert into a field called *monday* There is no such field. You only made:

- id
- time
- name
- text
- url

So inserting into monday won't work.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! I just copied the code snippet and didn't fully understand what it was doing. I don't have any experience with mysql and thought that would be necessary standard values. But now I know how to go on :)

Comment: I suggest creating the table in *phpmyadmin* then *export* the table structure then you have the correct sql. don't forget to change the prefix part. You way you created the table is pretty much by the book. So please do the ajax call by as it should be.